# $\sum^n_{k=0} {{k} \choose {l}} = {{n+1} \choose {l+1}}, n, l \in \mathbb{N}$ proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, induction

I need to prove that:
$$\sum^n_{k=0} {{k} \choose {l}} = {{n+1} \choose {l+1}}, n, l \in \mathbb{N}$$

This would look a simple sinduction proof but in that case I got a variables and I don't know what to do. Do I take my base as $n=1$ and $l=1$ and then prove for $n+1$ and $l+1$ at the same time? Or do I need to do that separately?

It looks pretty basic so I guess that there is solution somewhere on that forum, but I had no luck finding it.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Cf. [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule).

Comment: Yeah, thank you!